# php preg_match var length count?

Tags: php, regex

iv got a question in php regex.
For example if we use

```
<?php
 $str = '[code]anything[/code]';
 preg_replace('#\[code\](.*?)\[/code\]#is', 'Code:<pre>$1</pre>', $str)
?>
```

How i can make some thing like this to count the content

```
<?php
 $str = '[code]anything[/code]';
 preg_replace('#\[code\](.*?)\[/code\]#is', 'Code:'.strlen($1).'<pre>$1</pre>', $str)
?>
```

and that is my question.
hope i will find answer thanks.

Comment: You may want to take a look into the `preg_replace_callback()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
<?php
   $str = '[code]anything[/code]';
   $code = preg_replace('#\[code\](.*?)\[/code\]#is', '$1', $str);
   $output = 'Code:'.strlen($code).'<pre>'.$code.'</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: thanks it work
btw is there a way to make it in 1 line
in case of using array to parse more one than item.

Comment: What do you want to do? Capture a $1 and a $2 in your regex?

Comment: yep and i want to display  the number of its characters